# My margin-bottom works underneath a float in Chrome and FireFox, but it does not work in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, css, footer, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I want to have a margin underneath my float that separates my float from my footer.  It works in FireFox and Chrome, but it does not work in Internet Explorer. I tried it in Internet Explorer 10 and it does not work.  How can I fix this?  This is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mainfloat">
    <div class="text_body">
      Text goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Footer goes here.
</div>
```

This is all of the relevant CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}

#mainfloat{
    float: left;
    position: relative; /*also important to add*/
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    min-height: 550px;
    min-width: 650px; /*this was commented out earlier*/
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 17%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 220px; /*makes space between float and footer*/
    padding:10px;
}

#footer{
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First try adding "display: inline-block" to #mainFloat" before any margin declarations. If that does't work, I would suggest making a css rule of "margin-top: 220px" that targets only IE. Sometimes IE is weird.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  I will try it right now.  Also, how do I do "margin-top: 220px" that targets only Internet Explorer?

Comment: On second thought. It may be easier to just apply the "margin-top:220px" straight to the footer instead, as well as "display:inline-block" at the beginning.

Comment: When you said display it in the beginning, do you mean in the wrapper, the float, the HTML, or something else?